# mysql_escape_string VS mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I know that `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated from 5.3 but what was the actual difference in `mysql_real_escape_string`.

What I thought was that `mysql_real_escape_string` is the exact same as `mysql_escape_string` apart from `mysql_real_escape_string` takes a second argument for the mysql resource.

So then I thought well surely there must be some difference as to how strings are handled because there would not be a need for 2 functions.

So then I thought that the difference was purely down to locale and character encodings?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The difference is that `mysql_escape_string` just treats the string as raw bytes, and adds escaping where it believes it's appropriate.

`mysql_real_escape_string`, on the other hand, uses the information about the character set used for the MySQL connection. This means the string is escaped while treating multi-byte characters properly; i.e., it won't insert escaping characters in the middle of a character. This is why you need a connection for `mysql_real_escape_string`; it's necessary in order to know how the string should be treated.

However, instead of escaping, it's a better idea to use parameterized queries from the MySQLi library; there has previously been bugs in the escaping routine, and it's possible that some could appear again. Parameterizing the query is much, much harder to mess up, so it's less likely that you can get compromised by a MySQL bug.

Comment: i use PDO, this was just something that I needed to know for educational purposes .

Comment: There's also a mysqli_escape_string(). Does also do the same thing as mysql_escape_string?? if mysql_escape_string is deprecated why there's this function available and in mysqli too???

Comment: @Lykos: [mysqli_escape_string is an alias for mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysqli_escape_string), so the problem only applies to the old mysql_* functions. I would assume this was done as a convenience for people migrating from mysql to mysqli.

Comment: So either mysqli_escape_string() or mysqli_real_escape_string() both do the same thing, right?

Comment: @Lykos: Correct, but as I write in the answer, you should really prefer parameterized queries over escaping. If you must, however, then you can use either - but I would probably prefer using mysqli_real_escape_string, just so you don't inadvertantly introduce a bug if you for some reason need to modify the script to run on a server that only has the old mysql module.

Answer (score 3):

Well... sort of, yes. It takes the character set of the MySQL connection into account.

http://php.net/mysql_escape_string

> This function is identical to `mysql_real_escape_string()` except that `mysql_real_escape_string()` takes a connection handler and escapes the string according to the current character set. `mysql_escape_string()` does not take a connection argument and does not respect the current charset setting.

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_escape_string` is not deprecated from 5.3 but, for 4.3.0 and above.
So any One using PHP version above/or 4.3.0 should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

if using `php < 4.3.0`, than make your `magic_quotes_gpc active` from php.ini, though it is recommended to update, but if your code will have problem than make sure you use, `magic_quotes_gpc` and `addslash` function rather than `mysql_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1):

now both of these functions are deprecated in

> PHP 4 >= 4.3.0 and PHP 5.
>   They recommend using `PDO_MySQL` extension